# nth selector cant target children in WordPress Admin Profile Page

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to hide the second table element with class="form-table" that is inside the form element with id="your-profile".
table is a direct descendant of form.

Here's the code that is not working:

```
#your-profile > table.form-table:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

I tested this using:

```
#your-profile > table.form-table {
  display: none;
}
```

and I was able to delete all tables with class="form-table".

Please note that this form is from the Wordpress Profile Page.

Here is the form:

```
<form id="your-profile" action="l/wp-admin/profile.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
   <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="8ae1affd7f"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/profile.php">        
   <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="from" value="profile">
      <input type="hidden" name="checkuser_id" value="36">
   </p>
   <h2>Personal Options</h2>
   <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
      <tbody>
         <tr class="user-admin-color-wrap">
            <th scope="row">Admin Color Scheme</th>
            <td>
               <fieldset id="color-picker" class="scheme-list">
                  <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Admin Color Scheme</span></legend>
                  <input type="hidden" id="color-nonce" name="color-nonce" value="f290674286">            
                  <div class="color-option selected">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_fresh" type="radio" value="fresh" class="tog" checked="checked">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#a0a5aa&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#00a0d2&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_fresh">Default</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #222">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #333">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #0073aa">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #00a0d2">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="color-option ">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_light" type="radio" value="light" class="tog">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="http://aniridia.local/wp-admin/css/colors/light/colors.min.css">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#999&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#ccc&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#ccc&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_light">Light</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #e5e5e5">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #999">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #d64e07">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #04a4cc">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="color-option ">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_blue" type="radio" value="blue" class="tog">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="http://aniridia.local/wp-admin/css/colors/blue/colors.min.css">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#e5f8ff&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_blue">Blue</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #096484">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #4796b3">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #52accc">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #74B6CE">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="color-option ">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_coffee" type="radio" value="coffee" class="tog">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="http://aniridia.local/wp-admin/css/colors/coffee/colors.min.css">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#f3f2f1&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_coffee">Coffee</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #46403c">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #59524c">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #c7a589">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #9ea476">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="color-option ">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_ectoplasm" type="radio" value="ectoplasm" class="tog">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="http://aniridia.local/wp-admin/css/colors/ectoplasm/colors.min.css">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#ece6f6&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_ectoplasm">Ectoplasm</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #413256">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #523f6d">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #a3b745">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #d46f15">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="color-option ">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_midnight" type="radio" value="midnight" class="tog">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="http://aniridia.local/wp-admin/css/colors/midnight/colors.min.css">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#f1f2f3&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_midnight">Midnight</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #25282b">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #363b3f">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #69a8bb">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #e14d43">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="color-option ">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_ocean" type="radio" value="ocean" class="tog">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="http://aniridia.local/wp-admin/css/colors/ocean/colors.min.css">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#f2fcff&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_ocean">Ocean</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #627c83">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #738e96">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #9ebaa0">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #aa9d88">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="color-option ">
                     <input name="admin_color" id="admin_color_sunrise" type="radio" value="sunrise" class="tog">
                     <input type="hidden" class="css_url" value="http://aniridia.local/wp-admin/css/colors/sunrise/colors.min.css">
                     <input type="hidden" class="icon_colors" value="{&quot;icons&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:&quot;#f3f1f1&quot;,&quot;focus&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;,&quot;current&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;}}">
                     <label for="admin_color_sunrise">Sunrise</label>
                     <table class="color-palette">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="background-color: #b43c38">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #cf4944">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #dd823b">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td style="background-color: #ccaf0b">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="show-admin-bar user-admin-bar-front-wrap">
            <th scope="row">Toolbar</th>
            <td>
               <label for="admin_bar_front">
               <input name="admin_bar_front" type="checkbox" id="admin_bar_front" value="1" checked="checked">
               Show Toolbar when viewing site            </label><br>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <h2>Name</h2>
   <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
      <tbody>
         <tr class="user-user-login-wrap">
            <th><label for="user_login">Username</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="test" disabled="disabled" class="regular-text"> <span class="description">Usernames cannot be changed.</span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-first-name-wrap">
            <th><label for="first_name">First Name</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" class="regular-text"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-last-name-wrap">
            <th><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" class="regular-text"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-nickname-wrap">
            <th><label for="nickname">Nickname <span class="description">(required)</span></label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="test" class="regular-text"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-display-name-wrap">
            <th><label for="display_name">Display name publicly as</label></th>
            <td>
               <select name="display_name" id="display_name">
                  <option selected="selected">test</option>
               </select>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <h2>Contact Info</h2>
   <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
      <tbody>
         <tr class="user-email-wrap">
            <th><label for="email">Email <span class="description">(required)</span></label></th>
            <td>
               <input type="email" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="email-description" value="test@test.com" class="regular-text ltr">
               <p class="description" id="email-description">
                  If you change this, we will send you an email at your new address to confirm it. <strong>The new address will not become active until confirmed.</strong>        
               </p>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-url-wrap">
            <th><label for="url">Website</label></th>
            <td><input type="url" name="url" id="url" value="" class="regular-text code"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <h2>About Yourself</h2>
   <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
      <tbody>
         <tr class="user-description-wrap">
            <th><label for="description">Biographical Info</label></th>
            <td>
               <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
               <p class="description">Share a little biographical information to fill out your profile. This may be shown publicly.</p>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-profile-picture">
            <th>Profile Picture</th>
            <td>
               <img alt="" src="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452?s=96&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452?s=192&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-96 photo" height="96" width="96">        
               <p class="description">
                  <a href="https://en.gravatar.com/">You can change your profile picture on Gravatar</a>.        
               </p>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <h2>Account Management</h2>
   <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
      <tbody>
         <tr id="password" class="user-pass1-wrap">
            <th><label for="pass1">New Password</label></th>
            <td>
               <input class="hidden" value=" "><!-- #24364 workaround -->
               <button type="button" class="button wp-generate-pw hide-if-no-js">Generate Password</button>
               <div class="wp-pwd hide-if-js" style="display: none;">
                  <span class="password-input-wrapper">
                  <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" class="regular-text" value="" autocomplete="off" data-pw="c^aFWr)L*v#HVDNtZU)*bZbL" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" disabled="">
                  </span>
                  <button type="button" class="button wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="Hide password">
                  <span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="text">Hide</span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="button wp-cancel-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="Cancel password change">
                  <span class="dashicons dashicons-no" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="text">Cancel</span>
                  </button>
                  <div style="" id="pass-strength-result" aria-live="polite"></div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-pass2-wrap hide-if-js" style="display: none;">
            <th scope="row"><label for="pass2">Repeat New Password</label></th>
            <td>
               <input name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" class="regular-text" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled="">
               <p class="description">Type your new password again.</p>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="pw-weak">
            <th>Confirm Password</th>
            <td>
               <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="pw_weak" class="pw-checkbox">
               <span id="pw-weak-text-label">Confirm use of potentially weak password</span>
               </label>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="user-sessions-wrap hide-if-no-js">
            <th>Sessions</th>
            <td aria-live="assertive">
               <div class="destroy-sessions"><button type="button" class="button" id="destroy-sessions">Log Out Everywhere Else</button></div>
               <p class="description">
                  Did you lose your phone or leave your account logged in at a public computer? You can log out everywhere else, and stay logged in here.            
               </p>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="36">
   <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Update Profile"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleaseuse nth-of-type selector instead of nth-child as following.

```css
#your-profile > .form-table:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```